# why cannot use "this" in the main method?

Tags: java

```
   public class example {

    int a = 0;

    public void m() {
        int b = this.a;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int c = this.a;
    }

}
```

I am new in java. Why I cannot use "this" in the main method?

Comment: main is static method but variable `a` is non static

Comment: Why to downvote without to mention why? It is a good question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`this` refers to the current object. However, the `main` method is static, which means that it is attached to the class, not to an object instance, hence there is no current object inside `main()`.

In order to use `this`, you need to create an instance of your class (actually, in this example, you do not use `this` since you have a separate object reference. But you could use `this` inside your `m()` method, for example, because `m()` is an instance method which lives in the context of an object):

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    example e = new example();
    int c=e.a;
}
```

By the way: You should get familiar with the Java naming conventions - Class names usually start with a capital  letter.

Answer (score 2):

You must create an instance of example

```
example e = new example()
e.m()
```

Answer (score 1):

Becasue main is `static`. To access `a` you should declare it as `static` as well. Static variables exist without any instance of the class. Non-static variables exist only if an instance exist, and each instance has its own attribute named `a`.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Example {

    int a = 0;

    // This is a non-static method, so it is attached with an instance 
    // of class Example and allows use of "this".
    public void m() {            
        int b = this.a;
    }

    // This is a static method, so it is attached with the class - Example
    // (not instance) and so it does not allow use of "this".
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int c = this.a; // Cannot use "this" in a static context.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to comments from Andreas

If you would like to use 'a'. Then you will have to instantiate new example [better make example class name as capital Eaxmple].

Something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Example e = new Example();
  int c = e.a;
}
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

The `main` method is static, meaning it can be called without instantiating `example` class (static methods can also be referred to as Class methods). This means that in the context of `main`, the variable `a` may not exist (because `example` is not an instantiated object). Likewise, you can't call `m` from `main` without first instantiating `example`:

```
public class example {

    int a=0;

    public void m(){
       // Do stuff
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
       example x = new example();
       x.m(); // This works
       m(); // This doesn't work
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Additional of [Andreas Fester](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13699378/2893073) answer:

```
/****GRAMMER:
 * 
 *  Why cannot use "this" in the main method?
 * 
 *  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * 
 *      "this" refers to the current object. However, the main method is static, 
 *      which means that it is attached to the class, not to an object instance.
 *  
 *      Which means that the static method can run without instantiate an object,
 *      Hence, there is no current "this" object inside of main().
 * 
 * 
 */

public class Test{
    int a ;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int c = this.a;   // Cannot use "this" in a static context, 
                          // because there isn't a "this".
    }
}
```